# sum of same year and same Id query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

My table is :

I have get this record through query :

```
var result = (from r in context.tbl_PlantDemand
              join d in context.tbl_NoOfPlantDemanded on r.Id equals d.PlantDemandId  
              join c in context.Clones on d.CloneId equals c.Id
              where r.PifId == pifId
              select new
                     {
                        FinancialYear = r.FinancialYearVal,
                        TypeId = r.PlantationType,
                        Amt = d.Demand
                     }).ToList();
```

Output:

```
    FinancialYear  TypeId       Amt
    ---------------------------------
    2015-16           1         100  
    2015-16           1         50  
    2015-16           1         20  
    2016-17           2         100 
    2016-17           2         10
```

I need a result with sum of `Amt` depending upon group by 2 column year & typeId

```
     FY    TId    Amt
  --------------------
  2015-16  1      170
  2016-17  2      110
```

I can easily sum with single group by column but don't know how can I sum with multiple columns. Please let me know if anyone knows

Comment: Are you sure for 2nd you need 130 amount not 110?

Comment: @Learning please check i have updated. you are right

Answer (score 1):

Looks for me that you don't have to group by `year`:

```
select max([Year]), [Type Id], sum([Amt])
from Table1
group by [Type Id]
```

<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c43a5/3)</kbd>

Comment: please i have added a query in c# aspx.cs page. so how can i make query in c#.